# Why can't Maven compile a Java enum with overloaded methods while Eclipse can?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, enums, compiler-errors

If I declare a method in a Java<sup>†</sup> enum instance (e.g. `SwallowSpecies.AFRICAN.calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity()`) which overloads a static method of the enum class (e.g. `SwallowSpecies.calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity(double, double)`), compiling with Maven<sup>‡</sup> results in the following compilation error:

> method calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity in enum  cannot be applied to given types;
>    required: no arguments
>    found: double,double
>    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

For some reason, the compiler can't find the method without it being qualified with its class `SwallowSpecies`. However, why is the exact same code valid according to the compiler used internally by Eclipse<sup>§</sup> for building?— here is the relevant code:

```
public enum SwallowSpecies {
    AFRICAN {

        double calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity() {
            // This line compiles within Eclipse but not when compiling with Maven
            return calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity(3.0, 0.5);
            // This line compiles both with Maven's and with Eclipse's compiler
//          return SwallowSpecies.calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity(3.0, 0.5);
        }

    };

    private static double calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity(final double maxWeight, final double weightRatio) {
        // Dummy logic
        return 1.0;
    }

}
```

Interestingly, an analogous case using an inner class instead of an enum is invalid both for Eclipse's compiler and for Maven's— What's the difference here?

```
public class SwallowSpecies {

    private static class African {
        double calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity() {
            // This line doesn't compile
            return calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity(3.0, 0.5);
            // This line does
//           return SwallowSpecies.calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity(3.0, 0.5);
        }
    }

    private static double calculateMaxAirspeedVelocity(final double maxWeight, final double weightRatio) {
        // Dummy logic
        return 1.0;
    }

}
```

---

<sup>†</sup>I tested this phenomenon using Maven's compiler `source` and `target` settings set to `1.6`, `1.7` and `1.8` and it occurs with all of these different settings.

<sup>‡</sup>Tested using Maven version `3.16.0-38-generic` and using

- Oracle's JDK version `1.8.0_91` from Ubuntu's DEB `oracle-java8-installer` version `8u92+8u91arm-2~really8u91~webupd8~0` as well as with
- OpenJDK version `1.7.0_101` from Ubuntu's DEB `openjdk-7-jdk` version `7u101-2.6.6-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`

<sup>§</sup>Version 4.5.2; build ID 20160218-0600

Comment: Mainly because the eclipse compiler (ecj) supports that syntax, and oracle's (which maven is using) does not.

Comment: Your comment reminded me of [a certain old quote](https://alunthomasevans.blogspot.com/2007/10/old-microsoft-joke.html#1299391538500783089)... but, seriously, does that then mean that one doesn't conform exactly to the language standard and the other does?

Comment: It means that you are comparing apples and oranges. Technically it might be an ecj bug, but I'm guessing they won't "fix" it.

Comment: At least to me, comparing the behavior two compilers which are supposed to conform to the same standard doesn't seem like "apples and oranges"...

Comment: What if the "standard" is small round fruit? You've  found one place where the compilers behave differently. That's not entirely shocking, because they **are** different.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know why (e.g. which one adheres to the standard and which doesn't and/or how the two compilers differ in method resolution behavior); Hence my question. I suppose curiosity is a Bad Thing?

Comment: Oracle **is** the standard. Therefore, as I said in an earlier comment, it is *technically* a bug in [ecj](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler/ecj/4.3.1). The Eclipse Compiler for Java was (mainly) written by IBM. And, apparently, is now called [JDT Core](https://eclipse.org/jdt/core/). [The More You Know](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_uLYbic99bDY/TUoMdRxVbWI/AAAAAAAAAco/As0DV9rVgMk/s1600/TheMoreYouKnow.gif).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed some differences between the oracle and the eclipse compiler.
Eclipse uses its own compiler because

> it allows to run and debug code which still contains unresolved errors.

see [enter link description here](https://eclipse.org/jdt/core/)

Different implementations bring the risk of different behavior, as you found here.

So far I always found the Oracle or OpenJdk compiler (that I use in maven) to be more strict than eclipse. 
In very rare cases (not more than once a year I would say) I had to make small adjustments so code compiles in maven as well as in eclipse.